# Proxy settings not applying on the internet explorer 10 or 11 ( Windows 10 )

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, group-policy

I am trying to apply the internet explorer proxy settings by following below links but its not working.

I can see the registry setting on the machine but on internet explorer settings could not find the proxy settings.

Any suggestions to troubleshoot further.

https://theitbros.com/config-internet-explorer-11-proxy-settings-gpo/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/47292/gpo-did-not-apply-for-ie-proxy-settings-on-rdp-ser.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/browsers/use-proxy-servers-with-ie

Regards,
Arif

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up proxy through your browser? For example, [the simple example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/browsers/media/use-proxy-servers-with-ie/browser-setting-to-bypass-address.png) given in [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/browsers/use-proxy-servers-with-ie), but if the **connections** tab does not exist in options, you can try to search for this path in the registry: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Control Panel`, find the `Connections Tab` option and modify its value From **1** to **0**.

If you want to configure proxy settings through registry, you could refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/askie/how-to-configure-proxy-settings-for-ie10-and-ie11-as-iem-is-not-available#2-the-alternative-way-of-configuring-the-proxy-setting-is-deploying-the-registries-keys-directly), do you mean that you cannot find the `ProxyEnable` option in this path `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`? If possible, could you provide a screenshot example of this path?

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.